# Produce nice looking Venn diagrams or other suitable graphical overlays of data sets

Tags: r, overlay, venn-diagram

Who can recommend an R script for very nice looking Venn diagrams or other suitable tools for overlaying datasets in R? I would like to overlay data from 3 (up to 10) datasets.

Comment: This isn't (IMO) a very good question for this venue; StackOverflow is mostly intended for *specific* *programming* questions, e.g. "I've got some Venn diagrams, here's the R code, but I want to improve them in [this specific way], how do I do that?" Your question isn't bad in any absolute sense, but it's not a great fit for SO - it's (1) broad ("nice Venn diagrams") and (2) looking for off-site resources

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google and also the [Venn diagram](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VennDiagram/index.html) package.

Answer (score 0):

Nice is subjective. I like the `venn` function in the `gplots`package. It is fast and straightforward. The input is a list of vectors.

```
library(gplots)
# some data
A <- c(1:10)
B <- c(5:15)
C <- c(16:20)
# venn
input <- list(A, B, C)
venn(input)
```